# iAd banner changes the frame.size of my SKScene

Tags: ios, ipad, sprite-kit, adbannerview

The first time a user clicks on an iAd banner, it displays correctly and then go back to my game.
The second click actually makes the ad behave as if it was in landscape mode:
So the right side of the view is aligned to the real right side of the tablet, as judged by the "nodes and fps" indicator.
But the dimension of the view is now 1024*768 instead of 768*1024.

Therefore, the center of the scene is almost at the left edge of the iPad!

I tried changing it programmatically in the delegate for bannerAds, without success. Indeed, the size value actually changes, but not my screen!

```
var currentOrientation:UIDeviceOrientation=UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait
var oldFrameSize:CGSize?

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    //pause game here

    currentOrientation=UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    oldFrameSize=self.frame.size
    println("Leave the application to the Ad")

    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(currentOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")

    switch(currentOrientation){
    case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "interfaceOrientation")
        break
    case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue, forKey: "interfaceOrientation")
        break
    default: break;
    }


    self.size=oldFrameSize!

    self.view?.clipsToBounds=true
    println(frame.size.width)
    println(oldFrameSize!.width)
    println(size.width)


    println("Close the Ad")

}
```

EDIT: here are snapshot of the differences between the first Ad display, and the second Ad display:

[image: First Ad]

[image: Second Ad]

Comment: Do you change orientation anywhere in your game. Auto rotation?

Comment: nope, my GameViewController contains this :     
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    }

Comment: Basically, what happens (in SandBox mode) seems like: the first Ad is shown in landscape, and I force well the portrait mode after removing the ad. The second Ad forces the Landscape mode, but even when displaying the Ad, the AdView is actually supposed to be portrait. Then, I force the portrait mode, so I have the exact opposite: something portrait displayed in Portrait Mode but adjusted to the dimensions of a landscape!!